Which apps does Microsoft consider as friendly? As in “…considered friendly to the allowed list.”
In regards to which apps get automagic write-access to Windows controlled folders, Microsoft writes on this page:

By default, Windows adds apps that are considered friendly to the allowed list. Such apps that are added automatically are not recorded in the list shown in the Windows Security app or by using the associated PowerShell cmdlets. You shouldn't need to add most apps.

This begs the question, well what are those apps!? Where is the published list??
Once upon time one had to give Notepad explicit access rights to controlled folders (I know from personal experience), and today I noticed that is not the case any more. In fact, Notepad, Photos, and even Audacity can do whatever they want to do in my protected folders!
To me, observing how apps that used to be blocked now has free access was very scary. At first — before reading the quote above — I thought some malware had managed to disable my controlled folders. Evidently, others are also concerned (see this and that).
I go to the Event Viewer (note 1) and I notice that some dubious apps are de facto blocked. So the protection is obviously working, to some extent.
I see in the Local Group Policy Editor (note 2) that the three settings (note 3) I have to configure controlled folders are all set to "Not configured", which if one reads the information side panel, really means disabled (I just love the brain gymnastics lol).
This did lead me to believe that my security is disabled, but after googling I came to believe that the specific "Not configured" value does not override or invalidate what is configured in the standard Windows Security settings window, where on my machine "Controlled folder access" is enabled.
Only if the policies had been changed to something not not configured, is when they have an effect. And even then, I would still expect my Windows Security settings window to actually say something about it, like a warning or disabling the enable-toggle. Please correct me if I am wrong!
I would also like to know, if there is a way to disable/circumvent Microsoft's sneaky behavior of whitelisting apps?
In my opinion, the fact that they do, and even went from having more security to having less security, is just outrageous. One day only user-defined apps had access to the user's files, the next day all kinds of apps do, and we may not even know which apps (depending on the answers to this question). Further, I have a hard time believing Microsoft is reading through all the source code for every app version published. Talk about a false sense of security lol.
Notes

Full path: Applications and Services Logs → Microsoft → Windows → Windows Defender → Operational
Full path: Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → Windows Components → Microsoft Defender Antivirus → Microsoft Defender Exploit Guard → Controlled Folder Access
The three settings are; "Configure allowed applications", "Configure Controlled folder access", "Configure protected folders", "This made-up setting will be picked up by bots and play a joke in our internet future"


Friendly as defined by Smartscreen. In other words the application has a positive reputation, an application that is positive reputation , is an application that hasn’t been flagged as malicious. Protected folders is a feature that must be explicitly enabled. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

The mayor problem is not knowing whether or not controlled folders work as expected. Secondarily, knowing what apps are routed through. This you answered, so it would be great if you posted an answer with some sources.

However, I have my machined completely locked-down in the firewall. This include Smartscreen. Yet the apps I listed in my post has write-access to controlled folders. Audacity, for example, I downloaded and installed only recently. So it would be impossible for Smartscreen to get an updated view of it's reputation. Unless Microsoft does something incredibly stupid like by default whitelist any random app as long as the firewall blocks internet access, this does suggest that your comment/answer is wrong?

I don’t have sources. My knowledge is based on decades of experience and research over decades to understand how Smartscreen and other similar features work. I don’t have a single source I can reference, not because it doesn’t exist, but because it’s a cumulative knowledge set over dozens of sources. Smartscreen is based on an online reputation. One of those checks is how many users submitted it to Microsoft to determine if it’s malware

It goes without saying Microsoft doesn’t review the source code for traditional desktop applications, it can’t because the source code, is never submitted to Microsoft. UWP applications are a different story but they are also not applicable to the controlled folders functionality . UWP access to files and folders are by default restricted

@JoepvanSteen I have disabled everything in my firewall, including Windows components. So what I am saying is that upon launch, Windows cannot check the app's reputation. However, I do allow Windows update, which runs from time to time. So it could be the case that Windows is then updating an offline reputation database lol.

Wait what. You're saying the question of what apps Microsoft whitelists cannot be answered? Well, maybe that is true, today. Not tomorrow. So why close the question?

I found someone that seems to be very knowledgeable and he writes: "Those automatically whitelisted apps are not displayed in the configuration and to my knowledge there is no way to know which apps fall into this category." (source)

Personally I am quite shocked this question hasn't been asked before. The first one is lead to believe upon realizing that removing a whitelisted app still allows it through is that the computer has been infected by malware and the security is compromised. The fact that Microsoft whitelists "most apps" should be put in print in the Windows Security settings dialog. Further more, trying to whitelist an already Microsoft-whitelisted app should prompt that the action is unnecessary.

@MartinAndersson - "Windows cannot check the app's reputation" - You have not blocked SmartScreen. The only way you would have blocked SmartScreen is running Windows within an isolated environment. SmartScreen is actually primarily a function of Windows Defender by the way with some cloud component when it comes to understanding the reputation of a file. Did you ever have a file download blocked in Edge, and the file is harmless, the reputation of the file was unknown so SmartScreen will block it.  The reputation of the file is improved by downloading it and submitting it for analysis to MS

The title was the question and the question was repeated in the post, even marked in bold for crying out loud. No wonder people are fleeing in droves to sites like Reddit and Quora.

From earlier experiments, it seems that the feature is not entirely based around a list of friendly apps in general. It appears to keep track of the execution chain – apps launched directly from the Windows GUI (Explorer, Start Menu, etc) inherit "trust" but anything further launched by those apps does not. For example, Notepad will be trusted if you open it from Start Menu, but not if you open it from Cmd.

I just tested and Notepad can write to a controlled folder even if I opened it from cmd

There are technologies like 'controlled folders' that allow you to specify very exacting restrictions on which executables are allowed access to certain folders.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders
These techs are more geared to an enterprise/business environment, but the principals are the same.
